# material-ui: Get label from Chip component inside onClick() handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

-*- Material-UI / React / Redux -*-

I have a `material-ui` table. Inside each `<TableRow>` there are some `<TableCell>` components with their own `<Chip>` components. These `<Chip>` components are rendering text through the `label` property.

I need to be able to extract the label inside the `onClick` handler, which in my case is the `chipFilter()` function.

I am going to use that label to filter my redux state and return new data for the larger component rendering the table.

**Click Handler**

```
chipFilter = () => {
     console.log(this)
     console.log(this.props)
     console.log(this.props.label)
}
```

**Component render**

Each row that is rendered in the table:

```
<TableRow key={n.id}>    
    <TableCell 
        component="th" 
        align="center"
        scope="row">
        <Chip 
            label={n.procedure} 
            variant="outlined" 
            color="primary"
            clickable={true}
            onClick={this.chipFilter} />
    </TableCell>

    <TableCell align="center">
        <Chip 
            label={n.doctor} 
            variant="outlined" 
            color="primary"
            clickable={true}
            onClick={this.chipFilter} />
    </TableCell>
        .
        .
        .
</TableRow>
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution would be to update your `onClick` handler so that the `n` object which contains the meta data of the clicked `<Chip>` is passed through to `chipFilter()` like so:

```
<Chip label={n.procedure} variant="outlined" color="primary" clickable={true}
      onClick={ () => this.chipFilter(n) } />
```

And then update the `chipFilter` function as follows:

```
/* Item argument contains data for clicked chip component */
chipFilter = (item) => {
     console.log(this)
     console.log(item)
     console.log(item.label)
}
```

Comment: setting up my onClick like that gets it done. However, passing in only N sends the whole row into my onClick w/out any way to identify what was selected. So I simply did --> this.chipFilter(n.procedure)! Should be good to go with that. thank you